# Plotly-Dash: How to update only figure data without changing the figure layout?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a 3D scatter plot, I want to update the data of the figure (when moving a slider) without changing the 3D view.

Even with this solution, the 3D view is reset:

```
@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
              Input('slider', 'value'),
              State('graph', 'figure'))
def update_fig(value, figure):
    if value is not None:
        data = new_data(value)
        figure['data'][0]['x'] = data['x']
        figure['data'][0]['y'] = data['y']
        figure['data'][0]['z'] = data['z']
        return figure
    else:
        return figure
```

Is it possible to update only the coordinates of the points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following *should* do what you want:

```
fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
```

If it doesn't, then please consider providing a snippet with a sample of your data and a fully runnable dash setup. I'm sure we can figure it out somehow.

Comment: The value of `uirevision` here can be *anything*. The graph only changes when this value changes. If you don't want it to change, just set it to some constant string.